# Add a value to last row of multiple line cell in excel

Tags: excel

I have excel sheet with a column that contains multiple lines cells . I am trying to add a value to each cell after last entered value in it . 
Is this possible with a formula. ?

Comment: Without the use of selecting the cell and using enter + alt

Answer (score 0):

With the original in A2 and the new value in B2, put this in C2.

```
=a2&char(10)&b2
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jadeep , what if column A contains cells with different lines in each cell . E.g A2 3 lines , A3 6 lines and I just need to add the value to the bott of those cells ?